# IntelliJ и ANT

Tags: ant, java

Доброго времени суток.

Так получилось, что долгое время разрабатывался проект на Java. Его писало много разных людей. Сейчас есть необходимость его скомпилировать и запустить на сервере.
Для сборки проекта был выбран ant.

Для того, чтобы собрать конфигурацию, я в IntelliJ IDE выбрал
Build-> Generate Anr build

Создалась конфигурация. Далее, из консоли выполняю ant build Antxml.xml

Получаю на выходе большое кол-во warning-ов и это:

```
[javac] Note: Some input files additionally use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Some input files additionally use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] 2 errors
[javac] 100 warnings

BUILD FAILED
/repositories/EagleV1/module_eagle.xml:108: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details
```

Смотрю в module_eagle.xml:108.

Там вижу:

```
<javac destdir="${eagle.output.dir}" debug="${compiler.debug}" nowarn="${compiler.generate.no.warnings}" memorymaximumsize="${compiler.max.memory}" fork="true" executable="${module.jdk.bin.eagle}/javac">
      <compilerarg line="${compiler.args.eagle}"/>
      <bootclasspath refid="eagle.module.bootclasspath"/>
      <classpath refid="eagle.module.production.classpath"/>
      <src refid="eagle.module.sourcepath"/>
      <patternset refid="excluded.from.compilation.eagle"/>
</javac>
```

Вопрос: есть IDE нормально компилит проект, а ANT его отказывается собирать, что можно сделать?

P.S. Исправлять unchecked и deprecated не предлагайте. Слишком долгая песня.
Должна же быть какая-либо опция, чтобы игнорировать эти ошибки.

Comment: Если есть возможность, напишите для проекта нормальный билд с использованием maven или gradle. Я лично gradle люблю сильно за его простоту. Ant хорошо для простых вещей, а не для сборки многомодульных проектов. Если есть возможность дать доступ к исходникам, могу помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Задайте флаги компилятора через переменную `compiler.args.eagle`

```
 -Xlint:deprecation //игнорирование deprecated
 -Xlint:unchecked //игнорирование unsafe
```

Comment: Пробовал -Xlint:all. не помогло :(

Comment: @Станислав Комар вчитался более внимательно:  deprecated/unsafe это вообще не ошибки, а предупреждения, меж тем речь у вас идет именно об ошибках - внимательно изучите логи Ant и компилятора.